# How to add an overlay to an image in J2ME for Nokia SDK 2.0?

Tags: image, java-me, overlay, nokia

I have an image and I want to add an overlay or to find another way to combine two images in Nokia SDK 2.0 (J2ME)...
I need that one of the images to be partial transparent

Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking high level stuff (Form), since with low level stuff (Canvas) you can just draw the overlay on top of the images.
So, with high level stuff, I would extend the Image class, and add the overlay functionality in my own class.

Comment: I am talking about canvas ... didn't found anything working...

Comment: Why don't you just draw your overlay after drawing the image?

Comment: how ? I'm looking for some code doing that ...

Comment: Same way you'd draw any image.
First g.drawImage(someImage,x,y,anchor);
Then g.drawImage(overlayImage,x,y,anchor);

Answer (score 0):

For overlay in J2ME You should use JSR 234 AMMS this provide overlay control.